# How to generate an AdMob Ad Unit ID?

Tags: android, mobile, admob

How exactly are the ad unit ID strings used by AdMob created? More specifically:

1. Are they mechanically generated by AdMob? If so, where do you retrieve them from?
2. Are they manually composed by the developer? If so, what format and inputs are used to create them?

Please pardon the n00bling question, as I'm quite new to mobile development, and [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start#step_1_create_fragment_adxml) largely assumes you already have an ID.

My platform is Android, if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an admob account and in the adMob, for each advertisement you can get a unique ID thats generated by the system which you can use as shown in the documentation.